# How to specify a non-document theory file in ROOT?

Tags: isabelle

I import `Nominal2` into my main theory file and in Isabelle/jEdit I can use `atom_decl` so it works. In ROOT I tried various attempts to specify `Nominal2`, like

```
session "techreport" = "HOL" + 
   options [document = pdf, document_output = "output"] 
   theories [document = false] 
     Nominal2 
   theories 
     IsarIntroduction 
   files "document/root.tex"
```

but I get `bad input` or `No such file: "Nominal2.thy"`. I tried to specify a relative path from the dir of `IsarIntroduction`, and also from the dir of `root.tex`, in vain.

How can I specify the path for the `Nominal2` theory?

update: I use a purposely built Nominal2 image for Isabelle/JEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also be able to build on the session (image) Nominal2 like you do in Isabelle/jEdit. For instance:

```
session "techreport" = "Nominal2" + 
   options [document = pdf, document_output = "output"] 
   theories 
     IsarIntroduction 
   files "document/root.tex"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some fiddling led me to the solution.

The `No such file: "Nominal2.thy"` message came from the `isabelle build` process which does not see the pre-built image with `Nominal2` that Isabelle/jEdit uses. So giving the full path of `Nominal2` in the main theory file `IsarIntroduction.thy` and also in the `ROOT` file solved the problem.

There was one caveat though: I got a more than two hundred pages long document that included all the development of `Infinite_Set.thy`. The log contained

```
Loading theory "Infinite_Set" (required by "IsarIntroduction" 
via "Nominal2" via "Nominal2_Base")
```

So I had to include

```
theories [document = false]
  "Nominal2-Isabelle2013-1/Nominal/Nominal2"
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Infinite_Set"
```

in `ROOT` to prevent this to happen.

Comment: Just to clarify. Your solution is fine, but the reason for your troubles isn't that `isabelle build` doesn't see the `Nominal2` heap image as you state. In your `ROOT` file you never tried to load this image instead you indicate that the file `Nominal2.thy` (where the extension is implicit) should be loaded and for that you need the path. `isabelle build` sees pre-built images just fine, but you would have to incorporate them like lsf37 suggested.